# How to calculate the balancing of a matrix in python?

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, stochastic-process

I would like to perform a [matrix balancing](https://strathprints.strath.ac.uk/42589/1/fastbalance.pdf) in python. I thought to use [`linalg.matrix_balance`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.matrix_balance.html) in order to make the input matrix a [doubly stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix):

```
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,7], [9,1,1], [1,2,10*np.pi]])

y, permscale = linalg.matrix_balance(x)    
np.abs(x).sum(axis=0) / np.abs(x).sum(axis=1)        
np.abs(y).sum(axis=0) / np.abs(y).sum(axis=1)


permscale  

array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  2.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

It doesn't look that it actually balancing the rows and cols of the matrix. Any idea what should I do?

If I do: `y, permscale = linalg.matrix_balance(x, scale=False)`

The result isn't normalized either:

```
array([[ 1. , 2. , 7. ], [ 9. , 1. , 1. ], [ 1. , 2. , 31.41592654]])
```

Comment: The RAS method for matrix balancing is easily coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your analysis of the output, but mistaken in your consideration of what [`matrix_balance`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.matrix_balance.html) does. From the docs,

> The balanced matrix satisfies the following equality,
>
> B = inv(T) * A * T  (matrix products)

Which we can verify easily with your matrices,

```
>>>print(np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(permscale), x), permscale))

[[  1.           4.           7.        ]
 [  4.5          1.           0.5       ]
 [  1.           4.          31.41592654]]
```

Which is indeed `y`. This implies `matrix_balance` works as it claims to do. You claim,

> It doesn't look that it actually balancing the rows and cols of the matrix. Any idea what should I do?

But this is not true: the L1 norms of this modified matrix *are* balanced, to within one order of magnitude of two, such that the precise orders of magnitude are reflected to the scaling matrix `permscale`.

Is your aim instead to make your matrix doubly-stochastic, rather than (just) balanced? If so, you could look at *e.g.* [this project](https://pypi.org/project/sinkhorn_knopp/). Following the guide presented there I found the following doubly-stochastic matrix for your data,

```
>>>print(sk.fit(x))

[[ 0.1385636   0.55482644  0.30660996]
 [ 0.79518122  0.17688932  0.02792947]
 [ 0.06695665  0.26810303  0.66494032]]

>>>print(sk.fit(x).sum(axis=0), sk.fit(x).sum(axis=1))

[ 1.00070147  0.99981878  0.99947975] [ 1.  1.  1.]
```

Which ought to be 'close enough' for most use-cases.

Comment: What about the other doubly stochastic balancing algorithms?Preferably something I can use `conda` to install.

Comment: @0x90 what about them? Balancing implies row and column sums must sum to unity, which is an optimisation problem (quasi)-Newton methods can be used for, as the paper you cite also shows (nice read btw). I only aimed to show you how you could use Sinkhorn-Knopp in Python, which I believe is the 'regular' approach to this problem.

Comment: Is there a matlab library you recommend on?

Comment: @0x90 I am afraid not - I do not use matlab all that often. An idea is to re-write the matlab code provided by the paper to Python, and use [matrix_balance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.matrix_balance.html) for the initial guess? I'm just thinking out loud here, but would that help you along?